# glsl bind computed fragment shader to cube face

Tags: opengl-es, glsl

I have a cube , i want to bind a computed fragment shader to a cube face. any help?

my vertex shader is :

```
precision highp float;
attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec3 normal;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
varying vec3 fNormal;
varying vec3 fPosition;

void main()
{
  fNormal = normalize(normalMatrix * normal);
  vec4 pos = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
  fPosition = pos.xyz;
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * pos;
}
```

and my fragment shader:

```
precision highp float;
uniform float time;
uniform vec2 resolution;
varying vec3 fPosition;
varying vec3 fNormal;

void main()
{
  float minDimension = min(resolution.x, resolution.y);
    vec2 bounds = vec2(resolution.x / minDimension, resolution.y / minDimension);
    vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / minDimension;
    vec2 midUV = vec2(bounds.x * 0.5, bounds.y * 0.5);
    uv.xy-=midUV;

    float dist = sqrt(dot(uv, uv));
    float t = smoothstep(0.2+0.1*cos(time), 0.1-0.01, dist);
    vec4 disc_color=vec4(1.0,0.,0.,1.);
    vec4 bkg_color=vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    vec4 resultColor;
    resultColor = mix(bkg_color, disc_color, t);   
     gl_FragColor = resultColor;
}
```

i get a cube with a dot on the hole image.

but what i want is actually to have the dot on each face.

you can test the code directly under http://shdr.bkcore.com/

Comment: your current code does not have a light direction. If you wish to have light falling on each face, you might need more than one light sources as cube rotates more than one face needs to look illuminated. If you plan to display one face at a time, your one light source needs to move with respect to any rotations of cube. Anyway, just try passing light direction as `uniform`. And in FS, multiply it with `fNormal`. consider normalizing light dir in c++ code and fNomal in shader. btw, acc. to your current code, why do you use `fNormal`?

Comment: thx for your quick answer, but i think i couldn't explain my point so good.
let me try again.  if i have a fragment shader and i draw something on it, lets say a circle or a disk, how can i map that drawing to a face of a cube. i saw that gl_FragCoord is in window space, that's why my drawing will be on the hole screen and not on the cubes face , i'm i right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard approach to do this in OpenGL is to first render your content to a FBO (Frame Buffer Object). This allows you to render to a texture. You can then use this texture for one of the sides when rendering the cube.

The following is not complete code, but just an outline to give you a starting point:

```
// create a texture, and bind it
GLuint texId = 0;
glGenTextures(1, &texId);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);

// set texture parameters (filters, wrap mode, etc)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ...);

// allocate texture data (no data provided)
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_FLOAT, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);

// create and set up FBO with texture as attachment
GLuint fboId = 0;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fboId);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId, 0);

// create a depth renderbuffer and attach it if depth testing is needed

// start rendering
glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glDraw...(...);

// back to default framebuffer
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

// render cube using texture we rendered to
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
// rest of state setup and rendering
```

Answer (score 0):

thx for the answer, this is right, but i found a better way then rendering to a texture. i passed the texture coordinates and used them instead of the glfragcoord in the fragment shader.